# In Coinbase, how do I remove scope restrictions in my OAuth application?

Tags: ruby, oauth, scope, coinbase-api

I'm trying to use the Coinbase API for Ruby to create an application to accept Bitcoin payments.  I assume one way I can use their API is through their OAuth sequence.  So I created an OAuth 2 application on their site.  It has these scope restrictions by default ...

```
•   wallet:transactions:send is limited $1.00/day per user
•   wallet:transactions:send:bypass-2fa is disabled
```

with a link that reads "Please verify your identity to upgrade limits."  When I click on the link, it gives me two options

```
Buy limits (where I can upload my ID) or 
Sell limits (where I'm given a link to "Verify my Identity")
```

Which of these do I need to use in order to achieve what I want?

Answer (score 0):

According to the Coinbase documentation on [Send Limits](https://developers.coinbase.com/docs/wallet/coinbase-connect/permissions#send-limits)...

> To better protect Coinbase users, the wallet:transactions:send permission requires additional OAuth authorize parameters and two factor authentication.

This implies that Coinbase limits the funds that are sent, likely to protect users from accidentally emptying their accounts by a software bug. However your app is being built to *receive* payments, which is not governed by this limitation. Your app should be able to receive payments as fast as they arrive!

Of course, when you try to withdraw funds from your account, you will run into these or similar limits. But that would be a great problem to have.